# Let $u$ and $v$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Evaluate $\|3u - 2v\|$ given that $\|u\| = 4, \|v\| = 5$, and $u\cdot v= 3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I kind of see the reason why I need dot product in here, but I don't know how to use the dot product to help me figure out this question.

Comment: Write $\|3u-2v\|^2=\langle 3u-2v,\ 3u-2v \rangle$ and use the bilinearity of the scalar product.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\|3u-2v\|^2 = (3u-2v)\cdot(3u-2v) = (9u\cdot u) -(12u\cdot v) + (4v\cdot v).
$$